# Add string at the beginning of a generated file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a Windows script that iterates through all my sub folders to look for every single zip file it finds and puts their absolute paths in a bat file.

```
dir /b /s /-p *.zip /o:n | findstr /E .zip  >"%CD%"\listFichierZip.bat
```

I'd want now to change each line into a MOVE function.

1. Add MOVE before each path
2. Append the destination folder at the end of each path

I've encountered some issues, trying to add the "MOVE" string before the findstr function. I know how to concat strings, variables but function returns, I do not.

I found some threads asking this question on StackOverflow but all were about Unix, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    > "moveFichierZip.bat" (
        for /r %%a in ("*.zip") do echo move "%%~fa" "x:\somewhere"
    )
```

Use a recursive `for` command to search all the `.zip` files and for each one `echo` the `move` text followed by the file with full path (`%%~fa`) and the target folder.

All the output is redirected to the final target file.

To directly run this from command line, use

```dos
>"moveFichierZip.bat" (for /r %a in ("*.zip") do @echo move "%~fa" "x:\somewhere")
```

Comment: @Gloups Note that if all you really want to do is move the ZIP files you can skip the step of creating the `moveFilchierZip.bat` file and just have the batch-file move the files directly: `for /r %%a in ("*.zip") do move "%%~fa" "x:\somewhere"`

Answer (score -1):

Your best option is to install [`busybox.exe`](https://frippery.org/busybox/) and get all relevant unix text tools in one executable. Then you will be able to

```
find . -name *.zip -print | xargs -i echo MOVE "{}" DestDir > "$CD"/listFichierZip.bat
```

and that will be it. Perform some checks before executing `listFichierZip.bat`...

Comment: *I found some threads asking this question on StackOverflow but all were about Unix, unfortunately.*

Comment: Your understanding of the quoted sentence from OP is “I don’t want Unix solutions”. My understanding is “I don’t know how to use Unix solutions”. So I think it helpful to show them how those Unix solutions can be used on Windows (useful for other times, too, since they are common, while almost nobody uses `cmd` in such cases). I added my answer _exactly_ because I had read the sentence you quote. That said, we differ, and I thank you very much for motivating your downvote. I wish every downvoter did so, what we differ on would be much clearer for everybody.

Comment: Donevote **without** comment `==` **mean guys**. Then when the tag is `cmd` the user wants the solution on this way, **but** you offer him/her to install `busybox.exe` that is another **problem** else, for him/her. whereas he/she cannot use **cmd** do you think he/she can ues **bash**?. I am glad you have not gotten mad :)

Comment: @Dario The quoted sentence from my post meant "I don't want Unix solutions" since this code will, in a short while, be executed on a production server. We don't want to install tier party tools unless absolutely necessary. Thanks for sharing though.

Comment: @Gloups Thank you for the clarification, quite reasonable. Next time, please, add more detail to avoid misunderstandings. I don’t delete my answer because I do think that `busybox` is a better environment than `cmd` and this suggestion might be useful for future readers who might not have your constraints.